# AS3 Render Shape to Bitmap with Antialias

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a drawn a Circle Shape in AS3. I want to render the Circle into a Bitmap with nice/antialiased Edges. Because I want it to work on Mobile Devices (Air Apps are limited to stagequality = low) I need a workaround. Any custom shape to bitmap renderer available?

Comment: bitmapData.draw(circle, null, null, null, null, true) ?

Comment: But that look ugly because stage.quality is set to low on Air Mobile apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure this solution would work for Air Mobile Apps, but worth looking into.

Didier Brun @ ByteArray.org posted an API used to draw primitive shapes (as BitmapData, not from Vector draw calls either), which might help you get your circles to draw the way you want.

http://www.bytearray.org/?p=67

Code Snippet (from that URL):

```
// create the BitmapData to work on
var pixels:Raster = new Raster(320, 240, true);

// draw stuff
pixels.drawRoundRect( new Rectangle ( 20, 20, 200, 100), 18, 0xFF00FFFF );
pixels.drawRect( new Rectangle ( 70, 70, 100, 100 ), 0xFF009900 );
pixels.filledTri( 40, 40, 80, 110, 50, 30, 0xFF998811 );
pixels.aaCircle(100, 100, 40, 0x77AA88 );
pixels.circle(40, 40, 30, 0xFF000000);
pixels.line(10, 10, 60, 80, 0xFF000000 );

// show it
addChild ( new Bitmap ( pixels ) );
```

Hopefully the library / source code is compatible for your project! :)

Answer (score 2):

Have you consider using the `drawWithQuality` method?

The `drawWithQuality()` method works exactly like the `draw()` method, but instead of using the `Stage.quality` property to determine the quality of vector rendering, you specify the quality parameter to the `drawWithQuality()` method.

Answer (score 1):

`StageQuality.LOW` is going to make your bitmap quality low if you're using `draw()` because the source will be of low quality whether it's on the DisplayList or not.

I don't think there's a way around this.. You'll have to load in circle graphics or import images to use.

Comment: Yes, that's why I asked if their is a "custom shape to bitmap renderer".

Comment: Alright well I don't see how you expect to get an antialiased circle as a result if there's no antialiased circle to begin with.. Might as well be asking if there's a way to render a circle as a triangle?

Comment: Can't the stageQuality be toggled to "HIGH" momentarily just before the call to draw(...) is made?

Comment: @bigp No, Mobile Air apps (Android) are limited to use "LOW" or "MEDIUM" only

Answer (score 1):

If it is only something simple as circle, you can synthesize smooth image pixel by pixel. Create BitmapData of sufficient size and loop on pixels. On every pixel, compute distance from center - if it less than circle radius - half of pixel diagonal, set pixel to circle color. If it greater than circle radius + half of pixel diagonal, call setPixel32(x, y, 0).
Pixels that won't pass both conditions are near the edge - to do exact antialiasing, you must compute how much of pixel is covered by circle. Maybe you can find some convincing simple approximation. Good luck!

**Update:**
OK, I think I can remember simpler approach... You can draw your circle or any shapes two times bigger than they should be, then draw that bitmap into another with scale 0.5 (set through matrix) and smoothing on. That would be supersampling 4x. If stage quality doesn't affect bitmap smoothing, it should work.

Comment: Thanks but this is very difficult undertaking if I want to rasterize shapes that are only known at runtime :(

Answer (score 0):

In ActionScript 3 bitmap is created from **BitmapData**, so you need to create if first with

```
_bitmapData = new BitmapData(..
```

**BitmapData** has method **draw**, passing **DisplayObject** instance (**Sprite**, **MovieClip** or other) to it as parameter, will draw it's content into **BitmapData**.
Example:

```
var c:Sprite = new Sprite();
c.graphics.clear();
c.graphics.beginFill(0x00FF00, 0.5);
c.graphics.lineStyle(2.0);
c.graphics.drawRectangle(0, 0, 100, 100);
c.graphics.endFill();
var bd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(100, 100);
bd.draw(c);
var bitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bd);
```

Comment: Yes, this is correct. However, if the stage.quality  is set to low(I can't modify it in Air Mobile Apps), the output looks ugly :-/